# Minified plotly.js over 6MB

Tags: angular, webpack, plotly, plotly.js

I have an agular 14 project with plotly.js-dist-min 2.27.1 defined in package.json. The minified version should have **3.6 MB**, but when I run webpack-bundle-analyzer with prod build, it shows plotly.js-dist-min to be **6 MB**.

[image]

This is consistent also with the size of the whole prod build being 16 MB.

[image]

I was previously using plotly 1.58.4 directly included as js asset and I did not have that issue. (the scripts 3.32 MB is just plotly).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plotly comes with different bundles, as mentioned in the [readme](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/blob/master/dist/README.md)

Maybe you can switch to one of these lighter bundles to reduce the size.

Also kindly check if you have enabled `buildOptimizer` and `optimization` to true in `angular.json` for production build, maybe its turned off?

Comment: thx, yes setting these settings to true did the trick. (they were automatically set to false as part of migration of angular version). Now the size of plotly really is 3.5 MB and the raw size of the app is 6 MB.